# Trouble debugging Maven integration test in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, selenium

I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Win XP, with Maven 3.0.3.  I have created a Selenium 2 test that I wish to debug in Eclipse.  It is set up to run in the Maven integration test phase.  I'm using the Maven Cargo plugin with Tomcat as the container.  Here's the relevant section from my pom.xml ...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat${tomcat.major}x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${tomcat.major}/v${tomcat.version}/bin/apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}.tar.gz</url>
                        <downloadDir>${project.build.directory}/downloads</downloadDir>
                        <extractDir>${project.build.directory}/extracts</extractDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/tomcat${tomcat.major}x.log</output>
                    <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <home>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-${tomcat.version}/container</home>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <deployer>
                            <deployables>
                                <deployable>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                    <pingURL>http://localhost:8080/${project.artifactId}</pingURL>
                                    <pingTimeout>30000</pingTimeout>
                                    <properties>
                                        <context>${project.artifactId}</context>
                                    </properties>
                                </deployable>
                            </deployables>
                        </deployer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase -->
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Problem is, when I right click on my integration test in Eclipse, select "Debug As" and then choose my Debug Configuration (which is just the maven goal "clean install -Dtest=TableIntegrationTest"), the execution runs without hitting the breakpoint I set (http://screencast.com/t/at0AKWwxslE).  How can I do step-through debugging on a JUnit/Selenium integration test in Eclipse?

Answer (score 17):

Maven's integration tests by default run in a forked JVM. Therefore, eclipse is unable to attach to the forked JVM and see the breakpoints.

You can force the integration-test to run in the same JVM with the -DforkMode=never option.

More here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Edit: Updated link